# How to apply C++ fuzzing test on function that has nested Google protobuf arguments?

Tags: c++, testing, fuzzing, fuzzer

I'm trying to apply llvm fuzzer on my function which might have some `very complicated nested Google protobuf` as arguments to find possible crashes.

The testing code is shown below:

```
extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *data, size_t size) {
    MyProtoBufferType proto;
    if (!proto.ParseFromArray(data, size)) {
        // Handle parse error if necessary
        return 0;
    }

    // Call your function with the populated protobuf object
    myFunction(proto);

    return 0;
}
```

My question is:

1. How could the `proto.ParseFromArray(data, size)` succeed? It should be extreamly hard for the data to be parsed into my proto structure `correctly`(or I'm not sure if the correctness is not important under this circumstance), right?
2. Is there a more recommended approach for my situation？

Comment: This might be helpful. https://llvm.org/devmtg/2017-10/slides/Serebryany-Structure-aware%20fuzzing%20for%20Clang%20and%20LLVM%20with%20libprotobuf-mutator.pdf

Comment: If you want to test both data parsing and myFunction, then your code is correct - there is no need for parsing to always to succeed, crashes inside parsing are a valuable outcome.